# Regex modification

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am absolutely stuck when it comes to regex. I have been trying to modify the following expression to match URLs that begin with "www". It already matches URLs that begin with http, ftp, and https but not just plain www. I have not had much success on my own.

```
Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(^(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)")
```

Comment: Are you trying to find URLs in free text?

Comment: This one is for a URL field (hence the ^ in the front), but I do use this same regex (without the ^) elsewhere to find URLs in free text.

Comment: I can hardly see any relation to `asp.net` and even less to `asp.net-mvc` in your question so I am removing those tags.

Comment: Whatever, it's just what I'm coding the project in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make this...

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/
```

into this...

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/|www\.)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amber provided a direct answer to your question (so I gave it a +1) but I would like to point out another fact you should be thinking of.

**Detecting URLs in free text** isn't as trivial as one may think. Jeff Atwood has presented the problem very well in [his blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html). I suggest you read about it and get to know the problem.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's been functioning just fine as it is for months. It correctly detects URLs and transforms them into clickable links and has been doing its job quite well. I have had no issues. The only thing I want (and what this question was about) is to extend the expression to include www as a valid starting point for the match.

Comment: Detecting URLs in free text is mostly a matter of deciding what is "good enough" for your purposes. Jeff isn't really saying that detecting *most* URLs is hard, but rather that there are certain types of URLs that are annoying to find, and people should avoid those.

Comment: It is true that it's not perfect, but for my purposes it is fine. However, the point of my comment was not to continue the debate about validity of my approach. I was to make light of the fact that this is completely off-topic as the question is about how to modify the regex I have posted and not about whether or not I should be using regex to identify URLs.